# java use date string in url have exception

Tags: java

i have this url for webservice:

```
editProfile/1/2014-12-12/2014-12-12/New-Name
```

when i execute it i got this error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    java.util.Date.parse(Unknown Source)
    java.util.Date.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

#### code

```
new Date(newStartDate), new Date(newEndDate)
```

Comment: Show some code............

Comment: @TheNewIdiot i put the code, it is simple

Comment: What is `newStartDate` and `newEndDate` ?

Comment: How about reading the [javadoc of the Date constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28java.lang.String%29)? How about not using it, since it's deprecated? How about googling for "parse date in java", which will return thousands of answers?

Comment: @TheNewIdiot they are in the URl , 2014-12-12

Comment: @JBNizet I already did, but i couldn't solve the problem

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: Do you mean they're exactly "2014-12-12"? It would really help if you'd produce a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. Also, use SimpleDateFormat instead - or ideally use Joda Time.

Comment: Then re-read it. Especially the part saying that it's deprecated, and replaced by DateFormat.parse().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM"); 
    Date startDateObject;
    Date endDateObject;
    try {
        startDateObject = df.parse(newStartDate);
        endDateObject=df.parse(newEndDate);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Also you need to import:

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.Date;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using [Date(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28java.lang.String%29) which is the *deprecated* constructor , which internally uses [Date#parse(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29).

The Exception is clear . Read the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29)

> Attempts to interpret the string s as a representation of a date and time. If the attempt is successful, the time indicated is returned represented as the distance, measured in milliseconds, of that time from the epoch (00:00:00 GMT on January 1, 1970). **If the attempt fails, an IllegalArgumentException is thrown.**

Moreover , the method is **deprecated** .

Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by [DateFormat.parse(String s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: the `DateFormat` doesn't have a static method called parse

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: who said it was a static method? How about reading the documentation of DateFormat and SimpleDateFormat?